# How to know which of the geopoints is closest to my actual current location?

Tags: android, android-location, geopoints

Hope someone could shed some light on my problem.
I have 9 sets of geopoints data. Is there a way to decide/select which is the closest geopoint to my current GPS location(p1 to p9)?

```
public class LocationCalc extends Activity {
GeoPoint p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9;
float result;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_calc);
//<---GPS DATA starts here
String coordinates[] = {"2.976720", "101.7340622","2.9739549","101.7302322","2.9708705", "101.7306824","2.9700341", "101.7316818", "2.9681962", "101.7278519", "2.96585", "101.7311020", "2.9625874", "101.7255707", "2.9755125", "101.7287445", "2.9779000", "101.7305298" };
float lat0 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
float lng0 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
float lat1 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[2]);
float lng1 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[3]);
float lat2 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[4]);
float lng2 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[5]);
float lat3 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[6]);
float lng3 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[7]);
float lat4 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[8]);
float lng4 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[9]);
float lat5 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[10]);
float lng5 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[11]);
float lat6 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[12]);
float lng6 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[13]);
float lat7 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[14]);
float lng7 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[15]);
float lat8 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[16]);
float lng8 = Float.parseFloat(coordinates[17]);
p1 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat0*1E6),
    (int)(lng0*1E6));
p2 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat1*1E6),
    (int)(lng1*1E6));
p3 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat2*1E6),
    (int)(lng2*1E6));
p4 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat3*1E6),
    (int)(lng3*1E6));
p5 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat4*1E6),
    (int)(lng4*1E6));
p6 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat5*1E6),
    (int)(lng5*1E6));
p7 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat6*1E6),
    (int)(lng6*1E6));
p8 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat7*1E6),
    (int)(lng7*1E6));
p9 = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(lat8*1E6),
    (int)(lng8*1E6));


String[] myString = new String[17]; //create array
for (int number = 0; number < myString.length; number++) { 
    float[] result = new float[17];
    Location loc = null;
    Location.distanceBetween(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), lat[], lng[], result);


//<---- I'm stucked at this part where I'm not sure how to use For loop and to decide the shortest distance(p1 to p9)
}
}
```

added code, which im stucked at the distancebetween, my apology i'm still at the stage of learning android so much. i'm also find difficulties using For loop as mentioned by Eric below. Please do shed some lights. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Ken, have you find a solution for your problem ? hope you had, because, it was a very old post, can you please help me in this, now I'm on same situation .

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`Location.distanceBetween`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5b%5d%29)?

Such as:

```
float results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, results);
```

You can use this within a basic `for` loop to detect minimum value (`lat1` and `long1` can be the start point, and you can change `lat2` and `long2` on each iteration of the loop), then return the point with the least distance.

Comment: I'm relatively stucked...

I've posted my codes and can you have a look on it?

Comment: @Ken So, you have your coordinates in an array from 0-17. Run a loop from 2 to `coordinates.length`, with `i += 2`. Then use `coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[i], coordinates[i+1]` as the arguments to `distanceBetween`. And you only need `float[1]`, not 17.